# Как оформить отправку результата вычисления калькулятора на почту?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('Hello, world!');

  // ---------------------------------- Range slider jq ui
  $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.closest('.filter__slider'),
      min = parseInt($this.data('min')),
      max = parseInt($this.data('max')),
      from = container.find('.filter__slider-input-from'),
      to = container.find('.filter__slider-input-to');

    from.change(function() {
      $this.slider('values', 0, from.val());
    });

    to.change(function() {
      $this.slider('values', 1, to.val());
    });

    $this.slider({
      range: true,
      min: min,
      max: max,
      values: [min, max],
      slide: function(event, ui) { // При каждом перемещении
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(ui.values[0]);
        to.val(ui.values[1]);
        getDif(ui.values);
      },
      change: function(event, ui) { // В конце перетаскивания    
        console.log('change');
        getDif(ui.values);

        calcOne();
      },
      create: function() { // При создании виджета
        var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
        from.val(values[0]);
        to.val(values[1]);

        // getDif();
      },
      stop: function(event, ui) { // При завершении перетаскивания
        getDif(ui.values);
      }
    });
  });

  function getDif(values) {
    var total = 0;

    $('.filter__slider-element').each(function() { // Получение значений range слайдера
      var values = $(this).slider("option", "values");
      var dif = values[1] - values[0];
      total += dif;
    });

    //$("#totals").text(total);     
    return total;
  }

  function calcOne() {
    var total = 0;
    var range = getDif(); // Получаем значение range slider

    var count_1 = $("#count_1"), //ссылка на input
      type__select_1 = $("#type__select_1"), //ссылка на select 
      type__radio = $('input:radio'), //ссылка на радиобокс
      type__check_1 = $("#type__check_1"); //ссылка на чекбокс


    var input_val_1 = parseInt(count_1.val()),
      select_val_1 = parseInt($("#type__select_1 option:selected").val()),
      check_val_1 = (type__check_1.is(':checked') === true) ? parseInt(type__check_1.val()) : 0,
      radio_val_1 = parseInt($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());


    total += select_val_1;
    total += radio_val_1;
    total += check_val_1;
    total += parseInt(range);
    total = total * input_val_1;

    $("#totals").text(total);
    console.log(select_val_1);
  }

  $('select, input').change(function() {
    calcOne();
  });


  // Отправка формы\результата

  //Send on email
  (function() {

    var app = {

      init: function() {
        this.setUpListeners();
      },

      setUpListeners: function() {

        $(document).on('submit', 'form', this.submitForm);
        $(document).on('keyup', 'input', this.removeError);
      },

      submitForm: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this),
          btnSubmit = form.find('[type="submit"]');
        if (app.validateForm(form) === false) return false;

        btnSubmit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        var str = form.serialize();

        // str += $('#totals').text();

        console.log(str);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'contacts.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: str
        }).done(function(msg) {

          if (msg === "OK") {
            var res = "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"> <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message. </div>";
            $('.res-content').html(res);

            console.log('ok');
          } else {
            $('.res-content').html(msg);
          }

        }).always(function() {
          btnSubmit.removeAttr('disabled', '');
        });
      },

      validateForm: function(form) {
        var inputs = form.find('input'),
          valid = true;

        $.each(inputs, function(i, val) {
          var input = $(val),
            val = input.val(),
            formGroup = input.closest('.form-group');

          if (val.length === 0) {
            formGroup.addClass('has-danger');
            valid = false;
          } else {
            formGroup.addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-danger');
          }

        });

        return valid;
      },

      removeError: function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          formGroup = $this.closest('.form-group');

        formGroup.removeClass('has-danger');
      }
    }

    app.init();
  })();
});
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

.c-select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="c-select" id="type__select_1">
            <option selected value="0">Выбрать: </option>
            <option value="10">Вариант + 10</option>
            <option value="20">Вариант + 20</option>
            <option value="30">Вариант + 30</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Input Radio -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="c-input c-radio">
            <input id="radio-1" checked name="radio" type="radio" value="5">
            <span class="c-indicator"></span>
            5
          </label>
          <label class="c-input c-radio">
            <input id="radio-2" name="radio" type="radio" value="15">
            <span class="c-indicator"></span>
            15
          </label>
          <label class="c-input c-radio">
            <input id="radio-3" name="radio" type="radio" value="25">
            <span class="c-indicator"></span>
            25
          </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Input Checkbox -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="checkbox">
            Чекбокс +20:
            <label for="type__check_1" class="c-input c-checkbox">               
              <input type="checkbox" id="type__check_1" name="check-1" value="20" >
              <span class="c-indicator"></span>               
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="count_1">Кол-во:</label>
          <input type="text" id="count_1" value="1" name="input-1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="100"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="filter__slider">
            <div class="filter__slider-display">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-left">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">from</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-from">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="filter__slider-right">
                    <span class="filter__slider-text">to</span>
                    <input type="text" name="slider" class="form-control filter__slider-input filter__slider-input-to">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="filter__slider-element" data-min="0" data-max="300"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Total: <span id="totals">0</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="rom-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">отправить</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть [калькулятор](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/rLeybE).

Результат калькулятора записывается в span `id="totals"`.

Вопрос: как можно передать результат подсчета калькулятора (`id="totals`) вместе с `var str = form.serialize();` с помощью **ajax запроса**?

И как выглядит строка в **php** файле (если к примеру данные email почты в php файле выглядит как `$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);` ) ? `$calculateResult = ... $_POST['... '];` ?

Comment: записывать результат также и в `<input type="hidden" name="rezultat" id="rezultat"/>`, находящийся внутри формы; `$calculateResult =  $_POST['rezultat'];`

Comment: Спасибо, как-то не додумалась!

Comment: Не могу не выразить свое восхищение Вашей страницей на Гитхабе.

Comment: =) спасибо, очень приятно!

Comment: А можно код php contacts, если не сложно. Для ознакомления)